# Can I have Azure File Storage with Web App Service?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to Azure, using a free 30 day trial.

We are looking to move an existing ASP.NET website hosted on Godaddy to an Azure Web App Service.

The thing is, we have a folder in the ASP.NET website:

```
/files/image-store/
```

which holds thousands of PNG's and JPEG's. These images are shown in various aspx webpages on our ASP.NET website. It's currently around 2GB but could grow to multiple TBs.

I notice the free plan on the Azure Web App Service only allows 1GB of storage. I've read the following:

```
"Azure Files provides a cloud-based file share for storing and sharing files. 
You then access these files from applications hosted in Azure App Service, an
Azure VM, or an on-premises machine. Azure Files stores and shares file access
between applications and systems in a secure and failure-resilient manner."
```

But I also read on stack exchange that it only works on Linux with Azure App Service.

Is this still the case, and if so, is there a workaround?

BTW, I have been suggested a Blob is another way though we have no experience with that, seems we would have to make changes to a lot of existing code, and also not I'm not sure how transportable that code would be to other hosting providers if ever desired.

Comment: Are you hosting your application in Docker container?

Comment: @AndriyBilous No.

Comment: So you are using Azure App Service on Windows, correct?

Comment: @AndriyBilous Correct. Maybe Managed Disks is another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the response to the following question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/281069/can-i-have-azure-file-storage-with-web-app-service.html

Which basically refers to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-windows#configure-your-app-with-azure-storage

Which requires "An existing Windows Container app in Azure App Service"